# Is there a way to find all the correct dependency-version-ranges for a .cabal file?

Tags: haskell, cabal

I would like to give just the right dependency ranges for [a library published on hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/dump-0.2.8).

I would like to avoid being

- either too restrictive -- barring possible candidates, and possibly making the library uninstallable in certain sandboxes without manual edit to the cabal file,
- or too broad, resulting in build failures -- or even worse, passing build with faulty behaviour.

So, is there a way (e.g. with a script) to automatically find the correct dependency-version-ranges for a cabal package with which build succeeds and all tests pass?

Comment: If you are planning to use the information in a cabal config file for your own project, I would advise omitting the dependency ranges entirely. Cabal will automatically apply the widest possible dependency limits based on the necessary packages.

Comment: @Kwarrtz Are you reffering to the `cabal.sandbox.config` file? Because I mean the `<package-name>.cabal` file.

Comment: No, I am referring to the `.cabal` file.

Comment: You mean to ommit the ranges like in [this .cabal file](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/dump-0.2.8/dump.cabal)'s `build-depends` fields? Couldn't that result in failing build if for example an older version of a dependency is selected which has a different API?

Comment: @Kwarrtz That is extremely short-sighted advice. If publish a package like that to Hackage, you are announcing that your package can be built with all versions of all its dependencies. This is almost certainly untrue; and when you discover it later, you won't be able to fix it: you can release a new version with more restricted versions, but the version with the unrestricted bounds will be a "poison pill" that the dependency solver will always be willing to choose.

Comment: @DanielWagner So in your view it is better to start out with overly restrictive versions that are sure to work (compile and pass tests), and then broaden these restrictions in later releases if need be?

Comment: @DanielWagner Also, couldn't outdated, too broad versions be deprecated later and hence removing the poison-pill effect?

Comment: @DanielWagner Hackage now supports adjusting dependency versions after the fact. In fact Hackage trustees have been going around fixing problems this way.

Comment: @Wizek Last I heard the actual deprecation system wasn't really working (cabal doesn't give it the final say), and for really broken packages the most reliable fix is to adjust version bounds to something impossible. (I think `base < 0` has become a sort of standard for this.)

Comment: @Wizek Yes, I think making them restrictive and relaxing them as you discover you can is a sane alternative.

Answer (score 3):

Although I haven't used it myself, there is a tool [`cabal-rangefinder`](https://github.com/gelisam/cabal-rangefinder) designed to help with this.  Note that:

- It essentially does this by recompiling several times to test what versions work.
- It's not foolproof, as it makes some "reasonable" assumptions that aren't always true. (And without those, it would have to do a *lot* more recompiling to test *every* version.)
- It's probably still experimental (the author hasn't released to Hackage yet.)
- It doesn't yet run package tests, but there's [an issue](https://github.com/gelisam/cabal-rangefinder/issues/7) to add an option for this.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out!